# Can't migrate after installing Django Allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Help! I'm getting errors after installing Django AllAuth and migrating!

Errors:

```
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 93, in populate
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: auth
```

Installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.messages',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'videos',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Can anyone please help me? (edited)

Comment: show your ```INSTALLED_APPS``` in settings.py file

Comment: @shivankgtm Ok. I edited my post.

Comment: is it all in installed apps, I belive there are more into INSTALLED_APPS list

Comment: @shivankgtm yes, that is all in installed apps

Comment: 'django.contrib.auth'

is written two times in installed app, remove one

Comment: please post full list ```INSTALLED_APPS = [ ... ]```

Comment: @SourenGhosh thanks, but I still get errors

Comment: @shivankgtm Ok, I have now edited it.

Comment: what errors you are getting now after removing dupicates?

Comment: django.contrib.messages' is written twice..remove all duplicates it will work.